# Mysqli and binding multiple value sets during insert

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Hoping someone can give me some insight here.

When having to insert multiple rows into a table at once, I've used sql that looks something like this:

`INSERT INTO some_names (firstName, lastName) VALUES ('Joe', 'Smith'),('Fred','Sampson'),('Lisa','Pearce')`

As you can see I'm inserting three rows with one statement. The reason I do this is that I believe it is more efficient than executing three distinct statements to insert the rows.

So my question is this: how do I do this if I want to be able to bind my values to a statement? Unfortunately I've been looking all over the web and I can only find example of single statements in the form of:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO some_names (firstName, lastName) VALUES (?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $firstName, $lastName);
$firstName = "Joe";
$lastName = "Smith";
$stmt->execute();
$firstName = "Fred";
$lastName = "Sampson";
$stmt->execute();
```

It seems that this would be the equivalent of doing separate INSERT statements and seems to be less efficient.

So my question is: Is there any way to bind in a multi-insert statement? Please educate me here! Thanks

Comment: yes, but it would be less toilsome to concatenate. A duplicate question by the way

Comment: Thanks but if it is a duplicate, could you point me to where the other question is?

Comment: Here's the bad news. There are so many duplicate questions (on all topics) falling every day, that it makes impossible to find one particular. It's probably already buried somewhere below 300 other questions under mysqli tag, or so.

Comment: Yes, I've had a hard time trying to find the answer

Comment: personally I'd suggest either concatenate or - if you want to stick with native prepared statements at any cost - PDO will take about ten times less efforts creating a multi-insert query.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simple:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO some_names (firstName, lastName) VALUES (?, ?),(?,?),(?,?)")
$stmt->bind_param('ssssss', 'Joe', 'Smith','Fred','Sampson','Lisa','Pearce');
```

Comment: can you also use bind_param in a loop in that fashion? For example, `for(x=0 ...) { $name1 = $ar[$x]; $name2 = $ar[$x+1]; $stmt->bind_param($name1, $name2); }`

Comment: Also, I guess that you would still need to know the number of `?`s in the initial prepared statement anyway.

Comment: Can you explain why you use S's as the first parameter?  I understand that there are 6 because of the 6 fields, but I just don't understand why it's done this way.  It makes no sense to me (though yes, it does work and I did +1 it).

Comment: each 's' represent the type of the value - s is type "string" (this way mysql knows how to treat each parameter) - the types are i for integer, d for double(or float),s for string, and b for blob: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php - in this example all parameters are strings so you bind 6 S's :)

Answer (score 4):

> It seems that this would be the equivalent of doing separate INSERT statements and seems to be less efficient.

No, it’s not less efficient – because a statement is *prepared* only once (to figure out what it is supposed to do), and after that is done only the data is send to the database afterwards.

Comment: So, it seems that such a figuring out takes most of the resources, while actual disk writes, table locks, index rebuilding, separate network calls takes nothing. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at this the wrong way.

You would pretty much never do what you have shown above, it would almost always be done in a loop. And even if you dynamically constructed `(?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?)` you would still have to loop to build the query string and bind the data (which would get even more complicated because of MySQLi's ridiculous insistance on by-ref bindings) so it wouldn't gain you anything in terms of work that needs to be done by PHP - you just moved the loop - and it would lose you a *lot* in terms of readability.

It does have a gain in round trips to the database (assuming you are always inserting more than one row) - but this would only make a meaningful difference when inserting hundreds or thousands or rows, in which case you are most likely performing some kind of import operation, in which case the extra couple of seconds probably don't matter (it won't be e.g. slowing a page load).