# Mysqli multiple row insert, simple multi insert query

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

How do I insert this query with mysqli?...

```
INSERT INTO table (field1, field2, field3) VALUES ('value', 'value', 'value'), ('value', 'value', 'value'), ('value', 'value', 'value');
```

Normally in mysql this query is straight forward and will insert 3 rows, how do I do this in mysqli without using a prepared statement or maybe using a prepared statement but without getting too complicated?. I just wish to know if there is a way to execute such query without doing extra funky stuff in PHP.

In essence, I have some extracted data  that has around 10 rows per insert (and also needs multiple inserts in addition to having multiple rows), and this is what I need it for. I only wish to do this with a query as I have normally done it with mysql,  and not add multiple insert as one per each row.

Comment: mysqli is just a set of functions to send your query in mysql.

Comment: Store the SQL statement in  a variable and pass that to the mysqli_query as a parameter;

Comment: Sajuna unfortunately it can't be done that way. Mysqli is not the same as mysql.

Comment: Tried using mysql while there is a mysqli connection open, didn't work!.

Answer (score 23):

The mysqli class provides a number of different ways of accomplishing your inserts, each with its own benefits. Certainly, one of them should fit your needs.

The following examples assume that your unspecified "extracted data" is stored in an array of arrays: $bigArray[0...datasetsize][0...2].

The mysqli database is assumed to be $db.

**Method 1 - As Simple As Possible**

If you want to use a prepared statement and parameter binding, a first effort might look like the following. While not optimal, the statement is only prepared once. However, the variables are bound for each insert, which is wasteful (but simple). Since inserts are not bundled, the example loops over 10.

```
$statement = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO testTable (fieldA, fieldB, fieldC) VALUES (?,?,?)");
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; ++$i)
{
    $statement->bind_param("iii",$bigArray[$i][0],$bigArray[$i][1],$bigArray[$i][2]);
    $statement->execute();
}
```

**Method 2 - Optimized**

Prepared statements and multiple inserts combined enable performance which is nearly identical to the raw insert queries of Method 1. Actual results will vary depending on your setup, but a quick test on my system with both a local and a remote database showed performance a few percentage points **faster** with the optimized method, increasing a few points more if data in Method 1 needs to be escaped.

The following uses call_user_func_array, but you could avoid that if you know how many inserts you want to bundle each time and build call bind_param directly. That would further increase performance slightly.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO testTable (fieldA,fieldB,fieldC) VALUES (?,?,?)".str_repeat(",(?,?,?)",count($bigArray)-1);
$statement = $db->prepare($sql);

// This is the type string used by statement::bind_param. 
// s will be good for any type.
$types = str_repeat("s", count($bigArray) * count($bigArray[0]));

$values = array_merge(...$bigArray);
$statement->bind_param($types, ...$values);
$statement->execute();
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to AVOID,  like i said, I wanted to just pass the query, WITHOUT doing extra funky stuff in PHP, and is is a extreme example of funky stuff, in other words, I wanted to pass query as much as possible on its raw form.

Comment: @fyo but how would you deal with Method1 or Method2, if Data is _not_ stored in an _array_, but in an _JSON_ object? How to slice the hundreds or thousands JSON datasets into pieces of 10 to insert them at once?

Comment: what is $f in the answer ?

Answer (score -2):

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `aspnetuserroles` (`UserId`, `RoleId`)
         VALUES ('1', '8811404'), ('1', '1429d')";
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql); 

  if (mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)) {
       echo '<script language="javascript">';
       echo 'alert("Registeration Sucessfull!")';
       echo '</script>';
     
     } else {
             echo '<script language="javascript">';
             echo 'alert("User Role Registeration Failed!")';
             echo '</script>';
             echo $sql;
                            }
```

Answer (score -4):

Mysqli is not a database of it's own, but just a set of functions to send your query in old mysql.

So, using mysqli you can run any mysql query.

However, in case of dynamically supplied values you cannot avoid "extra funky stuff in PHP" as you are supposed to use **prepared statements** for that. And, unfortunately, raw mysqli is not that easy with them.

So, to perform such insert you will need to create a query with placeholders first

INSERT INTO table (field1,field2,field3) VALUES (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?);

then bind all the values using `call_user_func_array()`
and finally `execute`;

Comment: Okay, I guess I can do that. the whole query was actually prepared with php so it would be a long single query, but I guess I have to modify that to fit mysqli. Didn't want to do extra stuff for just an insert but I guess I have to adjust to mysqli. Thanks!, great answer.

Comment: Found a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15575405/mysqli-and-binding-multiple-value-sets-during-insert   but still no solution!!!!