# mysql_fetch_assoc data insert into mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

Below is my php form:

```
<form method="POST" action="finalc.php" name="sing">
  <table>
  <tr>
<td>Sl.No.</td>  <td>Date</td>  <td>Cus Id</td>  <td>Name</td>
<td>Sm1</td>  <td>Sm2</td>  <td>Sm3</td>  <td>Sm4</td> <td>Total</td> <td>Min</td>
  </tr>         
                    <?php                           
                     $i =0;
                     $sql = mysql_query("select date cus_id, name, sm1, sm2, sm3, sm4,
                            sum(sm1 + sm2 + sm3 + sm4) as total,
                            least(sm1, sm2, sm3, sm4) as min
                            from final");

                        $count = mysql_num_rows($sql);
                        if($count == 0){
                        ?>
                        <tr> 
                            <th><?php echo 'No Records Founds!' .mysql_error(); ?></th> 
                        </tr>
                        <?php 
                        }else{
                            while($sql_result = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
                        ?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $i += 1; ?></td>
<td><input type="text" name="date" value="<?php echo $sql_result['date']; ?>" ></td>
<td><input type="text" name="cus_id" value="<?php echo $sql_result['cus_id']; ?>" ></td>
<td><input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $sql_result['name']; ?>" ></td>
<td><input type="text" name="sm1" value="<?php echo $sql_result['sm1']; ?>" ></td>
<td><input type="text" name="sm2" value="<?php echo $sql_result['sm2']; ?>"</td>
<td><input type="text" name="sm3" value="<?php echo $sql_result['sm3']; ?>"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="sm4" value="<?php echo $sql_result['sm4']; ?>"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="total" value="<?php echo $sql_result['total']; ?>"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="min" value="<?php echo $sql_result['min']; ?>"></td>
</tr>
    <?php
    }
    }
    ?>
 </table>
<input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit"  />
</form>
```

My report table is as like :

```
Id  Date        Name   sm1  sm2  sm3  sm4  total  min
1   15/10/2017  aman   2    3    5    7    17     2
2   16/10/2017  anil   23   24   17   34   98     17
3
4
++
```

`final` table data comes from customer login. all the data from customer login shows here.

**Question** : In the `finalc.php` what will be the insert query to insert all the `mysql_fetch_assoc` multiple row data into mysql database with single submit button?

Comment: Please note that [mysql_* function have deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php) and i highly recommend you to switch to mysqli.

Comment: `mysql_*` is deprecated as of [tag:php-5.5]. So instead use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`.  
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php/14110189#14110189

Comment: _"what will be the insert query"_ - I guess it'll be the one you write, after you make an actual effort to inform yourself and read up on the necessary stuff ...?

Comment: Warning: Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really shouldn't user `mysql_*` functions. They are deprecated and vulnerable to sql injection attacks. They are completely removed from php 7 and forward, so if you use them your code will not be easily upgraded to future php versions.

Then there are some logical issues you will have to resolve yourself. You have the `min` and `total` values as input fields, however they can't be updated into the database directly, as they are not stored in your database but are only calculated when you select them. You are also fetching the `mobile` field while never using it, which is a sign (as in, it might be or it might not be) of a logical bug in your code.

Your html text inputs are also wrong. They all have the same name, no matter which row they are in, so the last row will always override all the other values. Try to submit your form and inspect the web traffic and `var_dump()` the `$_POST` superglobal, and you will see.

You can combat this by naming them as an array like

```
<input type="text" name="sm1[<?php echo $i; ?>]" value="<?php ... ?>" />
```

This will make each variable an associative array in php.

Furthermore, there seems to be an issue with your query. You never fetch date or name from the table, but you use them in your form.

It is also impossible to give you a solution when we don't know how your table looks like. But in general, you need to update your rows using the primary key of the table as a where clause. I'm going out on a limb here assuming `cus_id` is the primary key. In that cause, you could do something like:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $database);

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    // log & handle connection errors
    die();
}

$statement = $mysqli->prepare('INSERT INTO final (cus_id, name, date, sm1, sm2, sm3, sm4) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE');

foreach ($_POST['cus_id'] as $i => $cus_id) {
    $name = $_POST['name'][$i];
    $date = $_POST['date'][$i];
    $sm1  = $_POST['sm1'][$i];
    $sm2  = $_POST['sm2'][$i];
    $sm3  = $_POST['sm3'][$i];
    $sm4  = $_POST['sm4'][$i];
    $statement->bind_param('dssdddd', $cus_id, $name, $date, $sm1, $sm2, $sm3, $sm4);
    $statement->execute();
}

$statement->close();
$mysqli->close();
```

Though, please be advised this solution is not really suited if you intend to update thousands of rows. Then you should think about testing which rows to update first, or concatenating the insert like the most popular answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19512498/150926).

Also, you may want to read through the documenation on [mysqli](http://php.net/mysqli), especially [mysqli_result](http://php.net/mysqli_result) and [mysqli_stmt](http://php.net/mysqli_stmt).

Comment: With the code I am able to insert only the `last row` of the report table  not all the row.

Comment: Ok, I moved the bind_param into the foreach. Can you try this and test again?

Comment: Now this message comes:   `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in......`